# Connection error when trying to connect on oracle database with java agent in lotus

Tags: oracle, jdbc, lotus-notes

The following error is displayed when trying to connect to a database for the lotus notes java agent. JDBC Driver is stored on the server (myserver :/ opt/ibm/lotus/notes/85020/linux/jvm/lib/ext), so the driver loads only once and not several times when the same driver is embedded in the application . The problem is that the error does not happen when the driver is built into the application, but I can not leave it, the jar must be within the server. Does anyone have any idea what could be?

18/05/2012 21:44:18   Agent  error: java.sql.SQLException: Exceo de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you access the Oracle database using e.g. Telnet directly on the server? Perhaps a firewall is blocking the port? Make sure to check that everything works as expected from the server to the Oracle database.

Have a look at other answer on Oracla connection errors:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORACLE+The+Network+Adapter+could+not+establish+the+connection

Comment: Problem solved!
I checked the settings for the agent and set two parameters. marked:'Run as web user' and 'Allow restricted operations'. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

Since your code works when the jar is built into the agent but does not when it is external, I think it is likely that you are running into a problem with security restrictions.  By default, the Domino JVM limits the permissions for external jars, and I think that network access is one of the restricted areas.  The permissions can be adjusted by editing the jvm/lib/security/java.policy file.  You can find some information about it [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21279509).

Comment: I have another agent that accesses a PostGreSQL database that has the same configuration, the JDBC driver is inside the server lotus. This agent presents no problem. So I think security is not restricted. The question should be in the same connection because the driver is found (not show 'ClassNotFoundException'). The error happens when there is a connection: con = DriverManager.getConnection(xxxxxxx).

Comment: Problem solved!
I checked the settings for the agent and set two parameters. marked:'Run as web user' and 'Allow restricted operations'. Thanks for responding.